# My shiny app cannot be published and stopped by error 1 and "The following object is masked fromXXX"

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, publish

I do not know why I cannot publish my shiny app. It stopped by "The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

Last time, I successfully published, but this time I add some rmarkdown .rmd documents, so I can download pdf in shiny app. This works good.

But I do not know why I cannot publish it and I do not understand the error message.

Please help me, thank you so much！

"[image]

```html
   
   
   

Loading required package: magrittr
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : could not find function "windowsFonts"
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: That is not an error, just startup messages, use suppressMessages to suppress them and see if that works. The actual error is about the function WindowsFonts which is from `grDevices`. What OS are you using? Got  this error once while on a Unix system.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using windows computer. Since last time I successfully published it, I thought WindowsFonts do not need any packages. Thank you to tell me the package name.